# Overriding spring 3.1 properties in websphere console

Tags: java, spring, properties, websphere

I a'm developing web application for websphere 7.0. It's **XML** based spring **3.1** application. In my application I use many configuration properties files. But in production we don't have access to file system on websphere server, so we don't have access to spring or properties files or web.xml. Therefore we need override properties from configuration files in websphere administration console. But also we need programmatic access to resolved values of some properties overrided by administrator.

I've found that context:property-placeholder resolve both context parmeters and entry-env from web.xml and override properties from file as it should be in my application, but I don't know how to get properties programatically from context:property-placeholder(it's new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer).
And in my case I could not get util:properties to be overrided by context parameters or entry-env values. As and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Also I can't edit Context parameters from websphere administration console. I didn't find this functionality and google doesn't give answers. In console I can edit only servlet initialization parameters or entry-env values.

My situation:
web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/webappconf.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
     </listener-class>
  </listener> 

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/springServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>AA.AA</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>Override AA.AA</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>
```

webappconf.xml

```
  any properties resolver definition

  <bean id="springService" class="ru.test.krp.SpringService">
    <property name="a" value="${AA.AA}" />
    <property name="b" value="${BB.BB}" />
    <property name="c" value="${CC.CC}" />
    <property name="config" ref="any refrence to properties for access from code"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="springServlet" class="ru.test.krp.SpringServlet">
    <property name="springService" ref="springService"></property>
  </bean>
```

SpringService.java

```
public class SpringService {
  private String a;
  private String b;
  private String c;
  private Properties config;

  // getter/setter pairs
```

I will appreciate any help or ideas.

Answer (score -1):

You can put your configuration properties files into `shared libraries`. Library shoud be attached to your application.
All that you need to it's only how to reread new configuration.